# Python - Removing an element from a pandas dataframe so it can't be reselected in a For loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I'm trying to create a playing card dealing script in Python using Pandas dataframes. I want to be able to deal all 52 cards out, split evenly across 4 players (13 cards each).

Here's the initial set up:

```
Hearts = ["H1","H2","H3","H4","H5","H6","H7","H8","H9","H10","HJ","HQ","HK","HA"]
Spades = ["S1","S2","S3","S4","S5","S6","S7","S8","S9","S10","SJ","SQ","SK","SA"] 
Diamonds = ["D1","D2","D3","D4","D5","D6","D7","D8","D9","D10","DJ","DQ","DK","DA"]
Clubs = ["C1","C2","C3","C4","C5","C6","C7","C8","C9","C10","CJ","CQ","CK","CA"]

Deck = pd.DataFrame([Hearts,Spades,Diamonds,Clubs])
Dealt = pd.DataFrame([])

//Players:
P_1 = []
P_2 = []
P_3 = []
P_4 = []
```

I'm struggling to work out how to ensure each card that is dealt is unique.

My thought process took me to conclude that once a card is dealt, it should be

- appended to the applicable player list
- appended to the Dealt dataframe
- **removed** from the Deck dataframe to ensure the card doesn't get selected again

For further reference, here is the For loop I've created so far:

```
for i in range(52):
    Deal= choice(choice(Deck))
    if len(P_1)<= 12:
        P_1.append(Deal)
        Dealt.append(Deal)
    elif len(P_2)<= 12:
        P_2.append(Deal)
        Dealt.append(Deal)
    elif len(P_3)<= 12:
        P_3.append(Deal)
        Dealt.append(Deal)
    else:
        P_4.append(Deal)
        Dealt.append(Deal)
P_1.sort()
P_2.sort()
P_3.sort()
P_4.sort()

print('P1 Cards Sorted', P_1)
print('P2 Cards Sorted', P_2)
print('P3 Cards Sorted',P_3)
print('P4 Cards Sorted',P_4)
```

I'm just not too sure how to go about removing an element from a dataframe. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I can't see what is the benefit of using a DataFrame in your case when a simple list or a set would make things easier.

Comment: agreed, there's an easier way (I've just realised I could simply put all "cards" into one list, apply random.shuffle and then splice the list accordingly). That being said, I'm still interested to know if there is actually way to remove specific elements from a df in case I need to use it in a different scenario - new learner here, learning as I go

Comment: Of course, you can remove elements from a DataFrame. Have a look at df.drop() in pandas documentation.